# Bug trends vs Bug Progress

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, alm, mtm

What is the difference between Bug Trends and Bug Progress. The definitions from MSDN are confusing

You can use the Bug Progress report to understand how well the team is finding, fixing, and closing Bugs
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd695778.aspx

You can use the Bug Trends report to understand the rate at which the team is finding, fixing, and closing Bugs. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee461603.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trends report will show the rate vs Progress report shows volume of defects in each state. Both show data for a time period. They are two different ways of representing same data. With Trend report you can quickly see if the Arrival rate is higher than Closing rate, with Progress report you can exactly see how many bugs in each state.

Comment: Also found that Bug progess is for last 4 weeks and Trends is for last 7 days